# Alamofire Bad Network Connection | Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to implement a way to check if the network is weak or disconnected during network calls I perform using Alamofire 4.9 - the following is what I am currently attempting to do, but I have noticed that if the network it off it never jumps to this line:

```
URLError.Code.notConnectedToInternet
```

why does this occur, is there a better way of attempting this?

```
//Fetch new data
guard let url = URL(string: "test.com")
else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = "value1=test1&value2=test2".data(using: .utf8)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, _, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let res = try decoder.decode([Structure].self, from: data)
    }
}
catch {
    if let err = error as? URLError, err.code  == URLError.Code.notConnectedToInternet {
        // No internet
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of errors that can be produced by poor or entirely broken connectivity. `.notConnectedToInternet` is simply one of them. There is no single, exhaustive list provided by Apple of which errors may be returned when there are connectivity issues, so you'll want to experiment and see what you can produce. Additionally, there are a variety of errors which you can probably throw into a "network connectivity" bucket, such as `.dnsLookupFailed` or `.cannotConnectToHost`. Ultimately it may not be worth it to differentiate different types of `URLError`s.

By the way, you should use Alamofire 5 if you can, as Alamofire 4 is no longer supported.